# Orbeon How to validate on choice in dropdown list

Tags: validation, drop-down-menu, orbeon

- I have a dropdown list (Animal) with Pigs, Cows, Horses.
- I have a field (Number) for number of animals.
- I have a field (Weight) for total weight.

I choose an animal in the dropdown list, enter the number of animals and enter the total weight. Animals have different weights and I have to present a warning if the total weight is off limits for a specific animal.

I have tried with this formula for validation: `if ($Animal='Pigs') then ($Weight > $Number*200) else ($Weight < $Number*700)`.

I guess that there has to be a formula for each choice in the dropdown list.
It doesn't work an I have not been able to find a solution. 
Please help and I would also want to know - if it cannot be done.:)

Hi Avernet - thank you. I hope that I have added enough information below:

[Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyic3.png)

The source:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         fr:data-format-version="4.0.0">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>Slagtetal test</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>



                    <section-16>
                        <grid-17>
                            <grid-17-iteration>
                                <Species/>
                                <Number/>
                                <Weight/>
                            </grid-17-iteration>
                        </grid-17>
                    </section-16>


                </form>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">



                <xf:bind id="section-16-bind" ref="section-16" name="section-16">
                    <xf:bind id="grid-17-bind" ref="grid-17" name="grid-17">
                        <xf:bind id="grid-17-iteration-bind" ref="grid-17-iteration" name="grid-17-iteration">
                            <xf:bind id="Species-bind" ref="Species" name="Species" required="true()"/>
                            <xf:bind id="Number-bind" ref="Number" name="Number" required="true()" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xf:bind id="Weight-bind" ref="Weight" name="Weight" type="xf:decimal">
                                <xf:constraint id="validation-34-validation"
                                               value="if ($Species='Heste') then ($Weight &gt; $Number*200) else ($Weight &lt; $Number*700)"/>

                            </xf:bind>
                        </xf:bind>
                    </xf:bind>
                </xf:bind>


            </xf:bind>
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>24</application-name>
                    <form-name>Slagtetal-test</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="da">Slagtetal test</title>
                    <description xml:lang="da">Test af funktioner i blanketten</description>
                    <singleton>false</singleton>
                    <permissions>
                        <permission operations="update delete">
                            <owner/>
                        </permission>
                        <permission operations="create read"/>
                    </permissions>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments>
                    <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                    <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
                </attachments>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="da">




                        <Species>
                            <label>Animal species</label>
                            <hint/>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kvæg over 150kg over 2år</label>
                                <value>kvæg-over-150kg-over-2år</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kvæg over 150kg under 2år</label>
                                <value>kvæg-over-150kg-under-2år</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kvæg under 150kg</label>
                                <value>kvæg-under-150kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Svin over 27kg</label>
                                <value>svin-over-27kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Svin under 27kg</label>
                                <value>svin-under-27kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Søer og orner</label>
                                <value>søer-og-orner</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Vildsvin nedlagt</label>
                                <value>vildsvin-nedlagt</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Vildsvin opdrættet</label>
                                <value>vildsvin-opdrættet</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Får og geder 12-18kg over 18mdr</label>
                                <value>får-og-geder-12-18kg-over-18mdr</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Får og geder 12-18kg under 18mdr</label>
                                <value>får-og-geder-12-18kg-under-18mdr</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Får og geder over 18kg under 18mdr</label>
                                <value>får-og-geder-over-18kg-under-18mdr</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Får og geder over 18kg over 18mdr</label>
                                <value>får-og-geder-over-18kg-over-18mdr</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Får og geder under 12kg</label>
                                <value>får-og-geder-under-12kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Hjorte og andre drøvtyggere 12-18kg nedlagt</label>
                                <value>hjorte-og-andre-drøvtyggere-12-18kg-nedlagt</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Hjorte og andre drøvtyggere 12-18kg opdrættet</label>
                                <value>hjorte-og-andre-drøvtyggere-12-18kg-opdrættet</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Hjorte og andre drøvtyggere over 18kg nedlagt</label>
                                <value>hjorte-og-andre-drøvtyggere-over-18kg-nedlagt</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Hjorte og andre drøvtyggere over 18kg opdrættet</label>
                                <value>hjorte-og-andre-drøvtyggere-over-18kg-opdrættet</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Hjorte og andre drøvtyggere under 12kg nedlagt</label>
                                <value>hjorte-og-andre-drøvtyggere-under-12kg-nedlagt</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Hjorte og andre drøvtyggere under 12kg opdrættet</label>
                                <value>hjorte-og-andre-drøvtyggere-under-12kg-opdrættet</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Gæs 2-5kg</label>
                                <value>gæs-2-5kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Gæs over 5kg</label>
                                <value>gæs-over-5kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Gæs under 2kg</label>
                                <value>gæs-under-2kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Høns</label>
                                <value>høns</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kyllinger</label>
                                <value>kyllinger</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Duer</label>
                                <value>duer</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Ænder</label>
                                <value>ænder</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kalkuner over 5kg</label>
                                <value>kalkuner-over-5kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kaniner og småhårvildt under 2kg</label>
                                <value>kaniner-og-småhårvildt-under-2kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kaniner og småhårvildt over 2kg</label>
                                <value>kaniner-og-småhårvildt-over-2kg</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Kaniner og småhårvildt</label>
                                <value>kaniner-og-småhårvildt</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Heste</label>
                                <value>heste</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Opskåret kød (egne slagtninger)</label>
                                <value>opskåret-kød-(egne-slagtninger)</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Opskåret kød ialt</label>
                                <value>opskåret-kød-ialt</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Andre K &amp; V nedlagt</label>
                                <value>andre-k-&amp;-v-nedlagt</value>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <label>Andre K &amp; V opdrættet</label>
                                <value>andre-k-&amp;-v-opdrættet</value>
                            </item>
                        </Species>
                        <Number>
                            <label>Number of slaughtered animals</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </Number>
                        <Weight>
                            <label>Slaughtered weight</label>
                            <hint/>
                            <alert>Wrong slaughtered weight</alert>

                        </Weight>







                        <section-16>
                            <label>3. Dyreart</label>
                            <help/>
                        </section-16>


                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" id="grid-17-template">
                <grid-17-iteration>
                    <Species/>
                    <Number/>
                    <Weight/>
                </grid-17-iteration>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">



                <fr:section id="section-16-control" bind="section-16-bind">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-16/label"/>
                    <fr:grid id="grid-17-grid" bind="grid-17-bind" repeat="content" min="1"
                             template="instance('grid-17-template')">
                        <fr:c y="1" x="1" w="4">
                            <xf:select1 id="Species-control" bind="Species-bind" appearance="dropdown">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Species/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Species/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/Species/item">
                                    <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </xf:select1>
                        </fr:c>
                        <fr:c y="1" x="5" w="4">
                            <fr:number id="Number-control" bind="Number-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Number/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Number/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

                            </fr:number>
                        </fr:c>
                        <fr:c y="1" x="9" w="4">
                            <fr:number id="Weight-control" bind="Weight-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Weight/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Weight/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/Weight/alert" validation="validation-34-validation"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                            </fr:number>
                        </fr:c>
                    </fr:grid>
                </fr:section>


            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Comment: The validation has to be made on the Wieght field

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post pictures yet.

Comment: First, yes, it can be done (good news!), and what you're doing seems correct to me. Could you create a form from scratch that reproduces the problem (try to make it as simple as possible), and update your question to include the source of the form? (Also make sure to post a comment saying you did so, so we get a notification.)

Comment: Hi Avernat   I've just updated my question with a picture of the control and the source of the form

Comment: I think your expression is correct, except you need to have `$Species = 'heste'`, that is with a lowercase "h", since you're referring here to the *value*, not the *label*. You'll let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I have put 'heste' in the formula (lowercase) and the validation works on the first part of the formula, but not on the last part (after "else").

Comment: So you're saying that the other part, `$Weight < $Number*700` doesn't give you the result you expect? To debug this, try adding a column to the grid with a calculated value field, calculated as `$Weight < $Number*700`, and see what that gives you. And if you don't get want you expect, you can try even simpler expressions, like plain `$Weight` or plain `$Number`.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLaursen, did you manage to debug the issue, and make the calculations work the way you wanted?

Comment: Hi Avernat. It works with an added value field. I do have a problem with that: I don't want that extra field to be visible, but it doesn't work when i hide the field :( Is ther a way to make a hidden field relevant?

Comment: Bruno, the value of a field is calculated even if it isn't "relevant" (as it's called in XForms) or "visible" (as it's called in Form Builder). Are you seeing something different? Are you by any chance trying to access the value of the field from JavaScript? -Alex

Comment: Hi  Ales. It is a calculated field, that with validation and the validation doesn't work when the field is hidden. No JavaScript

Comment: Got it: you can have a hidden calculated field: its value will be calculated and updated even when the field is hidden, but it doesn't make much sense to put a validation on it. You should instead put it on fields where users enter values, like the number or weight field. And of course, that validation can use the hidden calculated value, if that makes things easier. Would that works for you?